# chrome extension doesn't work on "about:blank" URL

Tags: google-chrome-extension

Why my extension doesn't work on "about:blank" URL?

I've tried to add this into manifest.json:
`"permissions": [ "about:blank" ]`
and
`"matches": [ "about:blank" ]`
but it does not work...

Answer (score 5):

Try to set `match_about_blank` to `true` in `content_scripts`

[source](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/content_scripts)

Comment: This will only land in Chrome 37, according to the bug http://crbug.com/76429 linked by @RobW

Answer (score 3):

**Update:** As of May 15, [the issue](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=76429) is now fixed in Chrome 37.

**Original answer:**

The `about:` scheme is expressly excluded as a content script target, just like the `chrome:` scheme. From the documentation on [match patterns](http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/match_patterns):

> Host permissions and content script matching are based on a set of URLs defined by match patterns. A match pattern is essentially a URL that begins with a permitted scheme (`http`, `https`, `file`, `ftp`, or `chrome-extension`)...

As you can see, `about` is not a "permitted scheme" so what you're trying to do is likely impossible.

Comment: I have already activated "chrome:" URLs, I enabled the flag "#extensions-on-chrome-urls" or the switch "--extensions-on-chrome-urls", and added in manifest matches "chrome://*/*"

Comment: @RobW so is it still a bug?

Comment: @BrianMadarah Yes, the bug's status is "available", which means it is a valid bug available for someone to fix. When it is resolved, the status changes to "fixed" or similar.

Comment: @BrianMadarah Yes, but I've assigned it to me, so the fix will probably be available in Chrome 36.

Comment: @apsillers The issue has been resolved. Could you update your answer?

Comment: Not fixed in Chrome 36, but fix applied to Chrome 37.